# Show log from sub python function in AirFlow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'am facing with a little issue: I want to show all logs from all my python function opérateurs.

My Workflow:

- my main python function is using in pythonoperateur (everything in this function were printed to the airflow logs)
- my main python function calls other python functions but the print and logs in sub function not appear in airflow logs.

Even if I tried this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def subfunction():
   logging.info('This is an info message') #not show in airflow log

def main_function():
   print("call api") #it show in airflow log
   subfunction()
```

Comment: Does this issue occur also with INFO level or if you use print instead of logging?

Comment: Both. I'am using print and logging but none logs appear

Comment: That's weird. Please let me know what you get by running this DAG:   

def print_f2():
    print("print 2")

def print_f1():
    print("print 1")
    print_f2()


with airflow.DAG("bar", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    PythonOperator(task_id="foo", python_callable=print_f1)

Comment: thanks, but I find the problem. I use the same name for the pythonOperator variable, and my class/function

Comment: @zkta, you can post an answer for your own question. That will help another folks in the future :)

Comment: If the PythonOperator variable and the class / function have the same name they can collide and that could cause the problem, renaming any of them is a good idea. But please add an answer with the solution, this will be helpful for the community. On the other hand, if it is useful for you, to be able to visualize the logs there are two ways: if you run with test parameters on console then you can see them on console, otherwise, if you are running inside the web server then you can see them on the DAG registration page on the web page.